# Does gravity have any effect on metal casting?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aerospace-engineering, casting, production-technology

I wonder if the presence of a gravity field, makes any difference in the properties of the finished parts? 
That’s only if we can somehow, keep every other factor almost the same.

Comment: How can you pour the molten metal into the casting mold without gravity?

Comment: @SolarMike Centrifugal force! https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/67854/how-do-astronauts-get-drinking-water-iss, watch the video,

Answer (score 1):

It certainly does: any slag inclusions, for example, will tend to rise to the "top" surface of the casting, which hence furnishes an anisotropic distribution of inclusions in the finished part that depends on gravity.

If the sprue or gate that feeds molten metal into the mold cavity is on the "top" side of the mold, then breaking the gate remnant off the finished part is one way of eliminating flaws in it.

Answer (score 1):

Redundant ; How would you pour with no gravity; the metal would just sit in the ladle after you turn it upside-down. Floating of slag/dross , and hydrogen gas ( always present to some degree) would not happen.